# "An" oder "an dem" bzw. Artikel weglassen

Tags: article

Heißt es:

> Wir arbeiten **an dem** Arbeitspaket 1.

oder

> Wir arbeiten **an** Arbeitspaket 1.

Ich tendiere zu "an", da ich finde, der Artikel ist überflüssig. Warum aber der Artikel weggelassen werden kann erschließt sich mir nicht. Man würde ja auch nicht schreiben "wir arbeiten an Arbeitspaket".

Comment: Kannst du das mehr ausführen? Ich verstehe deine Irritation nicht.

Comment: Ich bin nicht unbedingt irritiert, ich frage mich nur warum ich hier den Artikel weglassen "möchte" und ob ich das überhaupt dürfte oder ggf. sogar sollte. Die Antwort mit dem Eigennamen hatte ich schon gefunden, mir war nur nicht klar, dass ich etwas einfach als Eigennamen annehmen darf und hatte gehofft hier gibt es noch weitere Regeln.

Comment: Bitte jede eigene Klärung (z.B. das mit dem Eigennamen) mit in die Frage aufnehmen.

Comment: Ich finde die Frage durchaus berechtigt und verstehe daher die Close-Votes nicht.

Comment: @Olafant: in der ersten Version war nicht klar worum es OP ging (ich dachte zuerst Dativ/Akkusativ) und ob er zumindest den Duden zu Rate gezogen hätte. Insofern kann ich das, auch wenn ich selbst nicht gewählt habe, schon verstehen.

Comment: @a_donda Ok. Aber jetzt ist es doch klar. Man kann doch Close Votes auch zurücknehmen, oder?

Comment: Wenn ich jetzt die Klärung mit dem Eigennamen aufnehmen würde, dann würde aber doch eine neue Frage draus, nämlich "Wann kann ich etwas als Eigennamen auffassen", oder?

Comment: @SebastianE Ja. Lass es mal einfach so. Du kannst ja für die Folgefrage eine neue Frage stellen. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In diesem Fall kann man den Artikel verwenden oder ihn weglassen. Das hängt davon ab, wie man "Arbeitspaket 1" grammatikalisch versteht.

Wenn man "Arbeitspaket 1" als Substantiv versteht, beziehungsweise als Substantiv mit einer Nummer, dann braucht man den Artikel. Dann funktioniert

> Wir bearbeiten *das Arbeitspaket 1*.

nicht anders als beispielsweise

> Wir streicheln den Hund.

Auf der anderen Seite kann man "Arbeitspaket 1" aber auch als Eigenname verstehen. In diesem Fall lässt man den Artikel weg. Dann funktioniert

> Wir bearbeiten *Arbeitspaket 1*.

nicht anders als beispielsweise

> Wir streicheln Fido.

Comment: Danke. Dann wäre die nächste Frage, nach welchen Regeln man etwas als Eigennamen verstehen darf. Mit muttersprachlichem Sprachgefühl kann ich "Hund" und "Fido" sicherlich selbst abgrenzen. Aber warum ist denn Arbeitspaket 1 plötzlich ein Eigennamen. Wir arbeiten "an Arbeitspaket" würde man ja niemals sagen.

Comment: @SebastianE Ich würde "Arbeitspaket 1" im Gegensatz zu "Arbeitspaket" (ohne Nummer) als eine Art Namen für *ein bestimmtes* Arbeitspaket betrachten. Ähnliches Beispiel: "Ich wähle (die) Antwort A."

Comment: Die Substantive für die Bezeichnung durchnummerierter Objekte oder Personen werden oft ohne Artikel benutzt: _Zimmer 23 wäre noch frei. Hund 1 wollte die Wurst nicht fressen, Hund 2 hat sich sofort darauf gestürzt. Wir kommen jetzt zu Kandidat 7. Auf Etage 3 ist die Fakultätsbibliothek der Anglisten._ Als Eigennamen sehe ich das nicht, allerdings als Identifizierungsmittel, wie Haus-, Chargen- und Sendungsnummern.